# Display specific content based on the click of the accordion tab in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need some help in the accordion tab functionality where by I need to display the specific content of that accordion tab on the right side of the form. I have all accordion on the left side of the form.

Here is the code that I am working on
**HTML and JS**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // activate Nestable for list 1
        $('#nestable').nestable({
                group: 1
            })
            .on('change', updateOutput);


 // output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));

$('#nestable-menu').on('click', function(e) {
   var target = $(e.target),
   action = target.data('action');
   if (action === 'expand-all') {
       $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
    }
  if (action === 'collapse-all') {
    $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
    $('.content:visible').slideUp();
   }
  });

$(function() {
   var nestablecount = 2;
   $('#appendnestable').click(function() {
       $('ol.outer').append('<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="' + nestablecount +
                    '"><div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content" name="' + nestablecount + '">Item ' + nestablecount + '</div><div id="c-' +
          nestablecount + '" class="content"><form role="form-' + nestablecount +
                    '"><div class="form-group"><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Phyllis Wheatley"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="name">Add a Description</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Quite the poet"></textarea><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="">Now you know it ;)</label><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">Yes</button></div></div></form></div></li>'
                );
      updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
      nestablecount++;
  });
        });
}
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                </div>
                <div class="dd" id="nestable">
                   <ol class="dd-list outer">
                     <li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="1">
                        <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                            <div class="dd3-content" name="1">
                             Item 1 
                             <span class="label label-default">New
                             </span>
                             </div>
                              
                      </li>
                   </ol>
                 </div>
                 <div id="nestable-menu">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="appendnestable">
                   <i class="fa fa-magic"></i> 
                   Add
                 </button>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <p><pre id="nestable-output"></pre></p>
</div>
```

What i am seeking help is that on the `nestable-output` i need to show something like
Clicked tab 1, if i clicked on the ITEM 1, and so on.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sampratid/934wuedv/1/)

Here is a reference that I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Hi, in your provided code you are printing json inside that pre tag and there only you need to print `item 1` ?

Comment: Hi @Swati, yes, to be more precise is that when i click on the Item 1, it will display card on the right with item 1 and a text box to change the name of the Item 1 to anything, as presented in the image above. Also, i dont want to show the data:1, 2 etc over there

Comment: @Swati also if you notice in the image, you will see that the heading on the accordion tab will change as per the text on the right side text box in the form

Comment: so you need to display whole `dd3-content` div (which has all your form..etc )on right side only for particular `li` which is clicked  and so on ?

Comment: @Swati yes correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `click` event for `li` tag so when its click get `data-id` value and then using this show/hide divs where `ids` matches.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$('#nestable').nestable({
  group: 1
})


$(function() {
  var nestablecount = 1;
  $('#appendnestable').click(function() {
    $('ol.outer').append('<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="' + nestablecount + '"><div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content" name="' + nestablecount + '">Item ' + nestablecount + '</div></li>');
    //append this inside nestable op
    $("#nestable-output").append('<div id="c-' +
      nestablecount + '" class="content"><form role="form-' + nestablecount + '"><div name="' + nestablecount + '">Item ' + nestablecount + '</div><div class="form-group"><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" class="form-control names" placeholder="Phyllis Wheatley"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="name">Add a Description</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Quite the poet"></textarea><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="">Now you know it ;)</label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right save">Yes</button></div></div></form></div>')
    $("#c-" + nestablecount).hide() //hide them
    nestablecount++;
  });
});

//onclick of li tag
$(document).on('click', '.dd-item', function() {
  var ids = "c-" + $(this).data('id') //get data-id
  //show that div
  $('#nestable-output div.content').not($("#" + ids)).hide()
  $("#" + ids).toggle() //hide other


})

//on click of yes :
$(document).on("click", ".save", function() {
  //get values 
  var new_names = $(this).closest("form").find(".names").val();
  var counts = $(this).closest('form').find("div[name]").attr('name');
  if (new_names != "") {
    //change them
    $(this).closest('form').find("div[name]").text(new_names)
    $(".outer li[data-id=" + counts + "] .dd3-content").text(new_names)
  } else {
    $(this).closest("form").find(".names").focus();

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/102306/jquery.nestable.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/102306/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/102306/jquery.nestable2.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/102306/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          </div>
          <div class="dd" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list outer">

            </ol>
          </div>
          <div id="nestable-menu">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="appendnestable">
            <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
            Add
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="nestable-output"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i edit the ```Item 1``` so that it changes both the places?

Comment: that name user should type in input-box inside form  and if click on *yes* you need to change new name both places am i right ?

Comment: thanks for the help @Swati. on the other hand,just wanted to see, is the left hand side side tab, can be an accordion too?

Comment: current updated code is not accordian now we are opening required div using jquery code  ..but you can do that  as well .

Comment: possible to help?

Comment: You can ask another question will help you there if i know :)